# Divs fail to center content horizontally on the page

Tags: html, css, materialize, centering

I've been using Materialize but hit a wall on this formatting. I can't seem to get it to center horizontally on the page. It just stays left justified no matter what change I make.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<div class="row center">
  <div class="col s1 m1">
    <i class="material-icons tiny">star</i>
    <p style="margin-top: -5px; font-size: .8em; margin-bottom: -10px;">2016</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col s1 m1">
    <i class="material-icons tiny">star</i>
    <p style="margin-top: -5px; font-size: .8em; margin-bottom: -10px;">2017</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col s1 m1">
    <i class="material-icons tiny">star</i>
    <p style="margin-top: -5px; font-size: .8em; margin-bottom: -10px;">2018</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wuz0rvh8/)

Comment: How about doing it like this? https://jsfiddle.net/wuz0rvh8/8/

Comment: Concerning @uom-pgregorio's response, keep in mind that !important should be avoided if not absolutely necessary, because it breaks the normal hierarchy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `col-offset-*`  utility class from materialize to center in the page

Also, avoid using inline-styles, instead use CSS classes

```css
.number {
  margin-top: -5px;
  font-size: .8em;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>



<div class="row center">
  <div class="col s1 offset-s5">
    <i class="material-icons tiny">star</i>
    <p class="number">2016</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col s1">
    <i class="material-icons tiny">star</i>
    <p class="number">2017</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col s1">
    <i class="material-icons tiny">star</i>
    <p class="number">2018</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This would work perfectly if it wasn't possible for some pages to have other than 3 stars/divs. Final product these are generated via Javascript and it's possible person A may have 4 years of data, while person B may only have 1.

Comment: Then add the `col-offset-s*` dynamically according to how many starts  it will have

Answer (score -1):

https://jsfiddle.net/wuz0rvh8/6/

```
table{
    display: table
}
```

I added that class in all the elements